# Visualizing Simultaneous Active/Inactive Events Over 24 Hours in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have the following type of data, representing possibly simultaneous events in a 24 hour period:

- Event Type: Start Time: End Time

Perhaps there are something like 50-100 different "types" and, typically, only 1-3 will be active at once [if it's important, perhaps assume no more than 5 are active at once].  I would like to create a visualization with time on one axis and a bar representing an active event.  However, I don't want to have 50-100 columns when only a few events will typically be active at once.  Is there a way to make excel fill the columns in order from left to right and label the different bars as pictured below?

If this is not possible in excel, is it possible with anything else?

[image: Example]

Comment: Is there a name for this kind of chart/graph? It's like a gantt chart but where multiple different "tasks" can share the same "lane" of the chart and it automatically keeps to the minimum number of lanes. Have done a bit of Googling, but can't figure out what the term for this is. If we knew what it was called, I expect we could find out how to achieve it in Excel (if it's possible).

Comment: I tried a lot of google searches, and the closest thing I was able to come up with was also a Gantt Chart.  It seems very natural to want to visualize some data in this way, so I'm sure it's been done before somewhere.

Comment: How is your data organized? I usually make Gantt chart by putting the description, start- and end dates in columns A, B and C and then adding a range of dates/times in the top row and use conditional formatting to see if  a cell falls within the start/end dates. Effectually creating a graph in the worksheet itself, using the cells as building blocks. Let me know if this sounds good, then I'll add it (with some more explanation) as an answer.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you can screw around with a Pivot table enough to make it work, potentially in conjunction with VBA.

Here's a few things that might help you get going:

1) Helper columns for your data. You might want to flag active events, duration, anything else you might want to see. Flagging active events is the only one I think you MUST have.

2) Turning it all into a pivot table. https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Create-a-PivotTable-to-analyze-worksheet-data-a9a84538-bfe9-40a9-a8e9-f99134456576 - easy how-to guide. You'll want your active event helpers as one of your filters

3) Automatically refreshing the data in the pivot table: http://www.get-digital-help.com/2011/06/13/auto-refresh-a-pivot-table-in-excel/ This is to constantly pull and update the table

4) Conditional formatting - Get the active events highlighted in a color, and inactive events not highlighted. Or something.

This is assuming you can get the data to be constantly updating in Excel. If the data is static, you can probably ignore a chunk of the auto-refreshing.